# Parsing json from external url Html and JS only

Tags: javascript, html, json, wordpress

```
<html>
<body>
 <div id="output">hi</div>
</body>
<script>
    var link="http://mywp.com/cilacap/api/get_posts/";
    var jcontent= JSON.parse(link);
    var output=document.getElementById('output');
    output.innerHTML=jcontent.id' ';
</script>

</html>
```

It only shows "hi".
Can someone tell me how to show JSON items such as "id" and "postDate"
with looping but without PHP scripting?

Thanks

Comment: is that link right path?

Comment: I've updated my answer, you should be able to copy paste the last part to make it work out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few syntactical errors, below is the right one.

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div id="output">hi</div>
</body>
<script>
    var link='{"url":"http://mywp.com/cilacap/api/get_posts/", "id":"url_id_01"}';
    var jcontent= JSON.parse(link);
    var output=document.getElementById('output');
    output.innerHTML=jcontent.id + ' ';
</script>

</html>
```

`JSON Data(var link)`, was not parsable.

`JSON Data(var link)`, didnt contained any attribute called `id`.

String concatenation in last line(`output.innerHTML`), was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quotes from:

```
output.innerHTML=jcontent.id' ';
```

and change it to:

```
output.innerHTML += jcontent.id;
```

Providing that the link is valid it should work now.

You can also write:

```
console.log(jcontent);
```

and check if the console displays the value, or any errors that have occurred.

Answer (score -1):

That url is a string, not json.

Use Ajax to get the data ( using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

```
var link;
$.ajax({

  url: "test.html",

}).done(function(data) {

  link = data;

});
```

Then, extract the data;

```
 output.innerHTML=jcontent.id;
```

Is for the value. You get the key like this:

**ES7**

```
Object.entries(jcontent)
.forEach(keyValuePair => 
{ 
    // Push to HTML

    var t = document.createTextNode(keyValuePair[0] + ' : ' + keyValuePair[1]);     // Create a text node
    output.appendChild(t);   
});
```

**ES6**

```
  Object.keys(jcontent)
  .map(key => [key, jcontent[key]])
  .forEach(keyValuePair => 
  { 
      // Push to HTML

      var t = document.createTextNode(keyValuePair[0] + ' : ' + keyValuePair[1]);     // Create a text node
    output.appendChild(t);   
});
```

**ES5** (Most likely your case)

Use `function` instead of `arrow functions` for *es5*:

```
Object.keys(jcontent)
.map(function(key){ [key, jcontent[key]] })
.forEach(function(keyValuePair)
{ 
    // Push to HTML

    var t = document.createTextNode(keyValuePair[0] + ' : ' + keyValuePair[1]);     // Create a text node
    output.appendChild(t);   
});
```

Access the value:

```
keyValuePair[0] // key
keyValuePair[1] // value
```

---

**Ps**

If you want to use the es7 or es6 method, have a look at [babeljs](http://babeljs.io)

Comment: Please JS Only.